# C++ STL Memory Allocator Compile Error

Tags: c++, memory, stl, allocator

I'm writing a C++ custom allocator for use with STL. When I put the following code in the class definition, it compiles:

```
#include "MyAlloc.hpp"

#if 1
template <typename T>
typename MyAlloc<T>::pointer
MyAlloc<T>::allocate(size_type n, MyAlloc<void>::const_pointer p) {
  void *ptr = getMemory(n*sizeof(T));

  typename MyAlloc<T>::pointer tptr = static_cast<MyAlloc<T>::pointer>(ptr);
  return tptr;
}
#endif
```

But when I put it in a separate .cpp file, I get the following error. What am I doing wrong? The error is on the static_cast line.

```
g++ -c MyAlloc.cpp
MyAlloc.cpp: In member function ‘typename MyAlloc<T>::pointer MyAlloc<T>::allocate(size_t, const void*)’:
MyAlloc.cpp:9: error: expected type-specifier
MyAlloc.cpp:9: error: expected `>'
MyAlloc.cpp:9: error: expected `('
MyAlloc.cpp:9: error: expected `)' before ‘;’ token
make: *** [MyAlloc.o] Error 1
```

PT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates must always be defined within a translation unit. In order to use the template function, the definition of the template needs to go in the header file, not a separate .cpp file.

Comment: -1. Answers a different question than the one that was asked, which had to do with a compiler error. Failure to define templates in headers leads to linking errors, but no linking was even being attempted.

Comment: No, it's a compiler error. The compiler cannot compile the template unless the template is defined within that translation unit. That's what header files are for -- to persist function/class/variable names across multiple implementation files.

Comment: What you're essentially saying is that an undefined function call (calling a function that does not exist) is a linker error -- it is not.

Comment: Note that it is still possible to separate the template declarations from the actual implementation by putting the implementation in a new file - I usually give them an .inl suffix - and then including the .inl file at the bottom of the .h / .hpp file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `typename` in front of `MyAlloc<T>::pointer`.  Because the type of `MyAlloc<T>` depends on `T`, the compiler doesn't know whether `pointer` is a typedef or a member variable or function. If you don't write `typename`, then the compiler assumes the latter.

Comment: And you can't put it in a separate implementation file.

Comment: +1, but I don't think that was the user's actual issue.